# I uninstalled mono, how do I reinstall it?

Tags: package-management, themes, mono

I uninstalled mono in 12.04 by:

```
   sudo apt-get remove mono-*
```

but afterward the theme of Ubuntu changed to an ugly one. It seems that some of the themes depend on mono!!!

My question is how can I revert packages removed by that command?

Comment: The command you ran removes all packages starting with mono- some of these have nothing to do with mono the free software implementation of .net. but are actually fonts and themes. They don't depend on mono at all. Maybe you should spend less time lessening to conspiracy theories and more time learning about ubuntu before you run any more commandline commands you don't understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because mono-* will mark more than just the mono framework for removal. It also removes some fonts and themes of the standard installation. Use

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

to reinstall the packages you removed accidentally. After that, you might need to reassign Ambiance as theme in the System Settings (under Appearance) and log off and on again.

Answer (score 2):

You removed MonoDevelop and it affected the theme? That's strange but you can install mono easily:

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely removed the package ubuntu-mono. This package contains monochrome icons, which are used for Ubuntu's consistent visual style. It may also have caused various reverse dependencies, such as themes, to have been removed.

jP_wanN's answer will help you fix the problem.